# Drawing straight line in unity terrain editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating terrain for my scene and I want to make a river, straight line throughout the map, I have multiple terrains that I need to go through. Is it possible to do it somehow?

Comment: It kind of depends on how you're editing the terrains, are you using terrain plugins from the store? Or manually editing the terrains? If it's manually, then you can use the terrain leveling tools to draw the river manually. If you want to use a river generator then you'll have to explore the terrain plugins on the store.

I've seen some river generating examples on youtube, but don't have the links i'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing this only by hand using basic tools Unity has to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the height map in a script and set it back to the terrain data in your terrain object (terrain.terrainData.SetHeights)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html